# Virtual Machine Connection tool on Windows 2012 Server Core with minimal Management UI?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-core

Is it possible to LOCALLY run the Windows Server 2012 "Virtual Machine Connection tool" on a Windows 2012 Server Core with minimal Management UI?

I want to run a minimalist 2012 Server Core with HyperV and load and switch among my "productivity" virtual guest OSes (some selection of Windows 8, an additional Windows Server 2012, Ubuntu, etc.) all on the same machine and simultaneously.  Is it possible to (graphically) connect to those desktops without a full desktop shell running on the primary 2012?

Since all I really want out of the VMC tool is a display surface - or even exactly a full screen with just one reserved keyboard to return to the host, the UI requirements are very light for the Core to satisfy.  (It would also be neat to be able to ctrl+alt+shift left and right to different loaded VMs)

(Please add a tag for windows-2012)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Server 2012, yes, you can.  You need to install the Hyper-V user interface components using dism.exe.